# TFS Release Burndown Report sprint list wrong

Tags: tfs, scrum

We have been using Scrum for a few months now and want to take advantage of the reports.  We are looking at the Release Burndown report.  It gives a list of the sprints.  There are 2 problems with the list of sprints.  The first sprint is listed twice for some reason, and it only shows sprint 1 -8 sprint 9 and 10 are not shown.

[image: Here's a screen shot of what I'm seeing]

Answer (score 0):

The report uses the data that is present in the olap cube. It is very likely that

1. There are two different iterations that have the same name, but internally they have different ID's. Could that be the case?
2. The 2 sprints that are missing probably have no work items assigned yet. The filter only shows sprints that are in the cube.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know what the olap cube is, how do I tell what the iterations are? The 2 sprints that are missing have work items assigned to them.

Comment: You can take a look at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/granth/archive/2010/07/12/monitoring-the-tfs-data-warehouse-faq.aspx

Comment: as well as http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb649552.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244706.aspx